# BASH (or other) script to move images or videos based on orientation?

Tags: scripting

New to scripting, been trying to figure this out for a few days now trying every combination of script I can find and I just can't seem to make it work.

What I am trying to accomplish is a simple script that takes an entire folder, creating landscape and portrait folders, first and then moves the images or videos into the proper folder either, landscape or horizontal.

I'm organizing 8TB's of video and this part of the process would save me a TON of time.

The best I've come up with so far is to use the script below and then manually separate the folders in finder and use Big Mean Folder Machine to dump them into the landscape and portrait folders.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

for f in *.{mp4,MP4,mov,MOV,m4v,M4V}
    do 
        height=`mdls -raw -name  kMDItemPixelHeight "$f"`
        width=`mdls -raw -name  kMDItemPixelWidth "$f"`
        mkdir -p "${height}x${width}"
        mv "$f" "${height}x${width}"/
        
        printf "File: $f\n"     
        printf "> Dimensions: $height x $width \n\n"
    done

printf "All done! \n"
```

I'm thinking there is a way to modify this so it uses "kMDItemOrientation" but I can't seem to get it to work. Maybe I'm way off, not sure.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just try to change it, use *height=* or *width=* for kMDItemOrientation (and delete the unused line)

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would just look at whether height is greater than width, e.g.

```
if [ ${height} -gt ${width} ]
then
  mv "${f}" portrait/
else
  mv "${f}" landscape/
fi
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Would I replace what's in between do and done with that code?

Comment: You'll need to keep the `height=` and `width=` lines because they are used in the `if`

Comment: Reason I ask if because no matter what I do it's moving them all into either the portrait or landscape folder. This is what I'm using.

#/bin/zsh
mkdir -p portraits
mkdir -p landscapes
for f in ./*.{mp4,MP4,mov,MOV,m4v,M4V}
do
  if [ ${pixelheight} -gt ${pixelwidth} ]  
  then
      echo "Portrait detected."
  mv "$f" portraits/
  elif [ ${pixelwidth} -gt ${pixelheight} ]  
  then
  echo "Landscape detected."
      mv "$f" landscapes/
  fi
done

Comment: There's no calculation of `pixelheight` or `pixelwidth` in what you just wrote.